# Access VB Error 3061: too few parameters, expected 1

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am writing a simple piece of SQL query to update a table in my test database, but I am encountering problems:

```
Public Sub UpdateStatus(TypeName As String)
Dim DBase As Database
Dim SQLCommand As String
Dim qdfChange As QueryDef
SQLCommand = "Update Case SET Status = 1 WHERE TypeName = '" & TypeName & "';"
Debug.Print SQLCommand

Set DBase = OpenDatabase("C:\TestDatabase\CaseSet.accdb")
Set qdfChange = DBase.CreateQueryDef("", SQLCommand)
qdfChange.Execute
End Sub
```

The field names in table Case match the ones in my SQL query.

(If this is of any value, this function belongs to a form)

Comment: Are you able to run your SQL directly? Is your actual column/table names a reserved word in Access? What data type is `bar` and `foo`?

Comment: foo is Number, bar is Short Text

Comment: Is `bar` getting properly set? Can you put a breakpoint on the `SQLCommand=` line and verify that `bar` has a value?

Comment: yes bar is set properly

Comment: Can you toss a `debug.print SQLCommand` line after your `SQLCommand=` line and then copy the `UPDATE` statement out of the immediate window and run it manually. Do you get the same error? Also, it wasn't stated in the question, which line does VBA break on when you click "Debug" when the error pops up?

Comment: Is table name, `field1`? Can you actually put the SQL statement which should not reveal personal/proprietary data?

Comment: @JNevill it breaks on the line qdfChange.Execute

Comment: All of this is pointing to an issue with the SQL statement that you are dynamically generating in this code. Again, try executing the SQL generated by this code directly in the database and you will find that you are getting the same error. As @Parfait is suggesting, the syntax should be: `UPDATE myTableNameHere SET field1=1 WHERE field2 = 'whatever is in bar variable';`

Comment: ok I've changed the code to the original, sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: @HansUp Running your suggested code produces the same error

Comment: Ok I've figured out the error. Somehow the database was modified by someone else and the field names were changed.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

[Case is a reserved word and TypeName is a VBA Function.](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#T)  That makes them poor choices for database object names.

If you can't rename them, bracket those names in your SQL statement so the db engine will recognize them as object names.

```vb
SQLCommand = "Update [Case] SET Status = 1 WHERE [TypeName] = '" & TypeName & "';"
```